# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Missing required member(s): conversionDestination, impressionData

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror

Chrome version :  89.0.4389.82

Application : ASP.NET

Suddenly every click on a link produce the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Missing required member(s): **conversionDestination**, **impressionData**.
at showDialog (windows.js:1032)

[image]

I turned off all extensions and experimental features, refresh script, restart IIS...still not working

I think it is related to conversion-measurement-api

https://wicg.github.io/conversion-measurement-api/

Comment: `var window = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);` remove the null? This method takes max. 3 params.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open take a look at

Answer (score 8):

SOLVED!!! window.open function has 3 params.

If you use 4 params you will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

I am facing the same issue with the error

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Missing required member(s): conversionDestination, impressionData.

on window.open on Google Chrome browser. It seems that the recent upgrade has broken something.

Comment: Having the same issue on anyone who updated their chrome to the latest version.

Comment: @A.R. Nasir Qureshi. Hello, 'I am facing the same issue...' is not an answer or a solution. Please consider, in such a case, adding a comment to the question itself instead. Thanks.

Comment: @primehunter. Understood. Will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently window.open has changed from 4 to 3 parameters at some point with no general announcement or documentation. A lot of older scripts are passing the 4th parameter to window.open as documented here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

As a result, a lot of websites are broken right now on the new versions of Chrome and MS Edge (also based on Chromium).

Comment: Where can I find a change log of window.open?